# Obtaining integer from room query math result

Tags: android, integer, android-room

I'm trying to obtain the result of a subtraction between two rows in the database.  Users specify the conditions on spinners (populated with the "model" column), press a button and the query is launched.

Spinners are properly saving the position into sharedpreferences and later obtaining it.

Button function:

```
public int value;

//later on
TextView converter = findViewById(R.id.converter);
        AppExecutors.getInstance().diskIO().execute(() -> {
    LiveData<Integer> value = mDb.personDao().loaddifferconstants(spinA, spinB);
    converter.setText(""+value); //quick dirty method
});
```

Dao

```
@Query("SELECT t1.const - t2.const AS result FROM person t1 JOIN person t2 WHERE t1.model == :spinA AND t2.model == :spinB")
LiveData<Integer> loaddifferconstants(String spinA , String spinB);
```

The query does work in DBBrowser, as a direct sql query. So I guess the error lies on how the result is processed into an integer. I tried listing the result, using both livedata integer, int, list... trying to pass it as a String... Failed.

**Update 1:**
Integer doesn't work either.
Actually Integer count doesn't work either, with the Dao being

```
@Query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PERSON")
    int count();
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
    LiveData<Integer> value = mDb.personDao().loaddifferconstants(spinA, spinB);
    converter.setText(""+value); //quick dirty method
```

`value` is a `LiveData`. This will cause the query to be executed *asynchronously*. By the next statement, that query will not have completed, and the `LiveData` will not have the query result.

Either:

- Remove `LiveData` from `loaddifferconstants()` and have it simply return `Integer`, so the query will be executed synchronously, or
- Consume the `LiveData` properly, by registering an observer

Since you seem to by trying to call those two lines inside your own background thread, I recommend the first approach: get rid of the `LiveData`. That would give you:

```java
@Query("SELECT t1.const - t2.const AS result FROM person t1 JOIN person t2 WHERE t1.model == :spinA AND t2.model == :spinB")
Integer loaddifferconstants(String spinA , String spinB);
```

Comment: I already tried "Integer" on both the Dao and the activity. It doesn't load. I also tried to CAST the values AS INT (they are numbers but the column data type is text).    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method package.database.PersonDao package.database.AppDatabase.personDao()' on a null object reference

Comment: @AlexT: Your exception is because `mDb` is `null`, apparently.

Comment: Thanks!! I copied the code from another activity and forgot to update the mDb to AppDatabase. Now it works when using Integer, as you suggested, but it only returns integer numbers. I'll see if I can figure out how to return decimal numbers...

Comment: In the end, I went with "Double value = AppDatabase.getInstance(this).personDao().loaddifferconstants(spinA,spinB);
" to get the number with decimals